# can we use CTE inside DB2 LUW trigger

Tags: db2

i am using DB2 LUW version 10.x

My question is can we use common table expression inside before insert trigger.

CREATE OR REPLACES TRIGGER TRG_TEST
BEFORE INSERT ON TEST
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN(
WITH DS AS (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM TEST)
SELECT 1 FROM DS
)

Comment: You probably have looked into the documentation for CREATE TRIGGER (https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/10.1.0?topic=rules-create-trigger) and checked the rules. CTE is possible, but it applies to sections of the trigger.

Answer (score 0):

The [CREATE TRIGGER statement](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/10.1.0?topic=rules-create-trigger) documentation topic definitely should describe in more detail, what *search-condition* is.
Actually a *search-condition* may contain [expressions](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/10.1.0?topic=elements-expressions), and you can use a *scalar-fullselect* as part of such an expression. But a [fullselect](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/10.1.0?topic=queries-fullselect) can't contain CTE. Only a [select-statement](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/10.1.0?topic=queries-select-statement) can.
So, you can't use CTEs in *search-condition*. If you really need it, then wrap your CTE in a function call.